# Storing Strings from Firebase as a List of String in Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am developing an app that retrieves strings from Firebase when launched. These strings are then stored in a shared preference. Later, the app retrieves the strings from the shared preference and creates a local list of strings. I use a RecyclerView adapter class to display the strings in the RecyclerView.

Here is an example of the sample data stored in the Firebase Realtime Database:

```
{
"art": [
{
"MrIncredibleArt": "stringexample4"
},
{
"GhostFace": "stringexample5"
},
...
],
"nsfw": [
{
"AnyLoser1": "stringtrollface1"
},
{
"AnyLoser2": "stringexample2"
},
...
]
}
```

To retrieve the values from the "art" key, I have attempted the following code to check if the data can be populated in the RecyclerView:

```java
public class MemeFragment extends Fragment {
List<String> asciiArts = new ArrayList<>();

u/Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meme_fragment, container, false);
initAsciiArts_Art();
RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_meme);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

try {
MemeAdapter_Meme adapter = new MemeAdapter_Meme(asciiArts, requireContext(), this);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
// Handle the exception here
}

return view;
}

private void initAsciiArts_Art() {
DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("art");
databaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
u/Override
public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for (DataSnapshot artSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
String asciiArt = (String) artSnapshot.getValue();
asciiArts.add(asciiArt);
}
}

u/Override
public void onCancelled(@NotNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
Log.e("Firebase", "Failed to retrieve art data: " + databaseError.getMessage());
}
});
}
}
```

However, the adapter is not being populated with the data using this approach.

Previously, all the strings were stored in the `strings.xml` file, and I was able to populate the adapter using the following code:

```java
private void initAsciiArts_Art_Local() {
try {
asciiArts.addAll(Arrays.asList(
getResources().getString(R.string.troll_face1),
getResources().getString(R.string.troll_face3),
...
));
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

This method worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The first code that loads from the database that I see is

```
private void initAsciiArts_Art() {
  DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("art");
  databaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot artSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String asciiArt = (String) artSnapshot.getValue();
        asciiArts.add(asciiArt);
      }
    }
    ...
```

And that loads this data:

```
"art": [
  {
    "MrIncredibleArt": "stringexample4"
  },
  {
    "GhostFace": "stringexample5"
  },
  ...
],
```

Now that the elements in the `art` array are **objects** here, not simple values. So the `artSnapshot.getValue()` is also an object, not a simple string. To get the key/value pair(s) in that object, you need to loop over its children again:

```
private void initAsciiArts_Art() {
  DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("art");
  databaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot artSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        for (DataSnapshot kvpSnapshot : artSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          String key = kvpSnapshot.getKey();
          String value = kvpSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
          Log.i("Firebase", key+": '"+value+"'");
          asciiArts.add(key);
        }
      }
    }
    ...
```

---

Finally note that you need to inform the adapter when you change its data, otherwise it won't be repainted. You can do that by [calling `notifyDataSetChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged()) on it at the end of `onDataChange`.

Comment: nope i tried both key and value still there are no values

Comment: it seems like it is unable to get data from firbase at all , thee are no logs

Comment: You posted a new question where you literally used the code from my answer. If my code doesn't help, why did you post a new question with it? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ --- Also: in the new question you don't call `notifyDataSetChanged`, which I explained in my last paragraph why it's needed and where to put it. --- Finally, the `return dataList;` returns the data list before it has any data in it, so won't work.